# Mix netcore project with .NET 4.5.1 project in same solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a netcore dotnet5.6 visual studio 2015 project in a solution.   I would like to add a class library project that targets .NET 4.5.1 to the same solution but I'm running into trouble.  Seems that I can use a solution global.json to help but the documentation is not clear to me. Has anyone tried this.   Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create ASP.NET Core Using .NET Framwork. Try to create a new Web Project and make sure you select the following template

**ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)**.